# Converting to Swift 3 error, value of optional type not unwrapped

Tags: swift

This code written with Swift 2 worked but not with Swift 3.

```
ShoppingManager.getShoppingItemsForPage(currentPage, pageSize: 40) { (shopItems: [ShopItemModel]?, error: Error?) -> () in
        if error == nil {

...

self.shopItems.append(Array(shopItems[10..<40]))
```

I get an error

`value of optional type [ShopItemModel] not unwrapped`.

I have tried using `?` but it doesn't work.

Here is my ShopItemModel

```
class ShopItemModel: NSObject {
    //RestKitMapping
    var itemID: String?
    var shopName: String?
```

Comment: where did you try using '?' ? as far as I can tell this should work: self.shopItems?.append(Array(shopItems?[10..<40]))

Comment: the  `shopItems?` produces a similar unwrapping error; `cannot use optional chaining on non optional ShopItemModel`\. Without the ? I get; `value of optional type ArraySlice...`...`

Comment: The compiler wants to unwrap `shopItems![10..<40]`. Consider to use a different name for the returned items to avoid a name clash.

Answer (score 0):

Unwrap your shopItems using a `guard let` statement else you can force unwrap using `!` but it will crash if shopItems is nil

```
guard let shopItemArray = shopItems else {
    return  // shopItems is nil if it goes here
}

self.shopItems.append(Array(shopItemArray[10..<40]))
```

Comment: What's the type of `self.shopItems` ?

Comment: it is of type [ShopItemModel] which is an NSObject containing optional properties.

Answer (score 0):

This compiles:

```
ShoppingManager.getShoppingItemsForPage(currentPage, pageSize: 40) { (shopItems: [ShopItemModel]?, error: Error?) -> () in
    if error == nil {
        let lastItem = self.shopItems.count

        if self.currentPage == 1 {
            self.shopItems.append(contentsOf: Array(shopItems![10..<40]))
        } else {
            self.shopItems.append(contentsOf: Array(shopItems!))
        }
```

Comment: the force unwrap isn't a very good practice to do as it can cause crashes, you should use `if let` or `guard let` statement to make sure your optional object exists